# Search operator trigger field validation in Filemaker

Tags: validation, filemaker

I'm having a bit of trouble with searching with search operators in validated fields in Filemaker Pro 13.

I have a field which has validation "*numeric only*", since it stores a numerical value. However, when I enter *find mode* I cannot use one of the pre-defined search operators such as * for "*zero or more characters*" or even # for "*any one digit*".

When I enter one of these operators in the field and try to search, Filemaker gives me a validation error and says that the field contents has to be numerical.

Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: IMHO, if you are getting a validation error, then you are not in Find mode.

Comment: That would be my assumption as well; but alas, I am.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in a brand new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's irritating.

I just:

- Created a test file
- Created a Number field
- Added the `Strict data type` option and set it to `Numeric Only`
- Made sure validation was set to `Only during data entry` which should not engage in find mode
- Created a couple of records and inserted values into the field
- Performed my find for `*` and got the same error message

This feels like a bug in FileMaker to me. I don't remember running into it in previous versions, but it could be there too. I would not consider Find Mode a data entry mode so you'd think the validation rules wouldn't apply.

All that said, you could use a calc field as a work around.

Crate a calculation field in the same table and name it yourfieldnameSEARCH, e.g. `idSEARCH`. The calculation for the field can just be the field you actually want to search on:

```
e.g. `mytable::idSEARCH = mytable::id`
```

You can set the index to `All` for the calculation field so that the searching is faster. Since the calculation field is in the same table as it's reference, modifications to the original field will be reflected in the calculation automatically.

Now you can search in the SEARCH specific field without the validation being applied.

As far as the "bug" itself, you can submit it to FileMaker and maybe they'll take care of it or at least explain why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is true going back at least as far as FileMaker 11.

The problem is that `*` and `#` are placeholders for characters in strings. The numerical operators, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `...` work just fine even with a strict data type of numeric only. `=` will also work to find blank values.

For a true numeric field, however, these should cover most of your searches:

- To find blank values, search for `=` in the numeric field.
- To find all non-blank values, search for `=` in the numeric field and click `omit` on the record.
- To find values between x and y use `x...y` in the search field.

Replicating the `#` operator is trickier. You could possibly replicate it with a new field that calculates the `mod` of a number or converts the numeric field to a string and get's the nth character.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this form of validation is intended for Text fields.

Note that *most* find operators do work, despite the validation:  `=`, `==`, `!`, `?`, `...` and all the comparison operators `< > ≤ ≥`.

If there is a bug here, it concerns the `#` operator, which Filemaker [expressly designates](http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/find_sort.5.7.html#1027993) to find "*one or more digits in a number field*".

Two possible workarounds:

1. Change the field's type to Text (note that this may affect the way the field is sorted);
2. Replace the strict numeric type validation with validation by calculation.